# Java super a toString method

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract

In a super abstract class I have a `toString` method and I want to inheritance it. How to do that?For example
`A a = new A(1,name);`
`A extends my superclass` and I want to the output to be "A with 1,name"

Comment: The A class will automatically inherit its parent's `toString()`. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Does this mean you actually have an abstract class, or is 'super abstract' just a figure of speech?

Comment: I want to use like super.toString() something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just re-write the `toString()` method in your derived class if this is what you are aiming for. If you do, don't forget the `@Override` annotation.

Comment: yep, but professor ask us to maximum use of inheritance

Comment: It does, overriding is a major feature of inheritance, one of the most powerful features of it.